# Using parameters in PDO prepared statements with DESCRIBE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, schema

It seems to me that this cose is ok with a standard query, but not when it comes to DESCRIBE:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare("DESCRIBE ?");
$q->execute(array($this->ormTable));
$table_fields = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Anyone can confirm? Are there workarounds other than appending manually the table name?

Comment: I don't believe that you can use a bound parameter for a table name at all.

Comment: You can't bind a parameter for a table or field name, or anything else that is syntax related to SQL. use a PHP $variable instead.

Comment: as dbf said, use a variable to insert SQL-query parts – but please escape them before, using [`PDO::quote()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

Comment: @feeela Yes I was already asking about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure ormTable can't be influenced from outside (SQL injection, etc) or quoted properly for syntax usage (do not use PDO::quote() for that)

```
$q = $dbh->prepare("DESCRIBE ".$this->ormTable);
$q->execute();
$table_fields = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Shouldn't I escape this first?! (with `PDO::quote')

Comment: Yep: `$dbh->prepare( 'DESCRIBE ' . $dbh->quote( $this->ormTable ) );`

Comment: Exactly, I had this concern... Thanks a lot

Comment: @feeela That wouldn't work I think. I am understanding that the quoting is for values, not for entities like fields or table names.

Comment: I think I must quote it myself with backticks after cleaning the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = $dbh->prepare(sprintf('DESCRIBE %s', $this->ormTable));
$q->execute();
$table_fields = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```